# Class not registered error on COM Visible Assembly - Registered for COM Interop (works on on Windows 10 machine - Class Not Registered on another)

Tags: c#, vba

I have a C# assembly with that is used by Access VBA.

1. The assembly works without any issues on one Windows 10 machine. Calls from VBA to the assembly are fully functional.
2. The same assembly throws a `Class not registered` when an assembly function is called the same VBA on another machine.
3. The Assembly successfully Builds in Visual Studio 2019 on both machines.
4. On both machines the assembly is successfully registered as a Reference in the `Tools | References` menu.
5. This is a .NET 4.7.2 Framework Assembly.  The Target Platform is `Any CPU`.
6. The Assembly is set at `Make Assembly COM-Visible` and `Register for COM Interop`.

There is an obvious difference between the two machines.  This seems like it may be a missing dependency. However, it appears all dependencies are available on both machines.

Would anyone know of any other possible causes or techniques to investigate this further?

Comment: This is a C# .NET Assembly specifically designed for use from Microsoft Access VBA.  The [VBA] tag is correct.

Comment: Without more info, it's hard to say. First place I'd check if the .NET version. If possible, try downgrading to `.NET 4.6`. (I think) this is the version that ships with all versions of windows